# Why closed as 'basic or trivia': Did most universities require Ancient Greek and Latin? From when to when?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why was https://history.stackexchange.com/q/23509/8309 closed?  My question is not answered in Wikipedia.
I cite the reason claimed by 4 of the 5 closers:

> "Requests for trivia or basic historical facts are off-topic if they can be easily answered by looking up the relevant topic on Wikipedia. We're trying to complement common historical references, not duplicate them." – Pieter Geerkens, Kobunite, CGCampbell, Tyler Durden

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I agree the close reason doesn't make much sense. However, that doesn't mean the question is a good fit for the site. You are asking about university curriculums in three countries and a continent for an unspecified timeframe; that's an incredibly broad question.

Comment: @Yannis What if I asked just for one country, ie the UK?

Comment: How about choosing just two universities - perhaps just Oxford and Cambridge - and a timeframe of less than 100 years?

Answer (score 1):

You asked two or three questions: 1) Do most universities require Ancient Greek or Latin? 2) From when to when? 3) And the implicit question was "where."

You defined "where" in your revision. That was good start. Now YOU should define "when to when." That narrows the question further. Perhaps you can narrow the question even more by specifying what types of universities: 1) National universities? 2"City" schools? 3) "Ag(gricultural) colleges (common in the U.S.)?

As asked, the question was "too broad." If you can narrow it enough, it might be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest school I can find matching your definition is the [University of Oxford, founded in 1096](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_university#Establishment), at which time the teaching of Latin was definitely on the curriculum. By the mid-Renaissance, say 1500 or so, Ancient Greek would have also been on the curriculum. Your time frame is just over 900 years, for more than half of which it is trivially determinable that both languages were on the curriculum.

Where is there in your posting a non-trivial question, not of unreasonably broad scope, that we can accept on the site?